# Stuck trying to connect to my mongodb server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. I have just started installing mongodb as per the manual specifies. I can start my server but when I try to open any page that requires the database i get this:

```
Started GET "/posts" for ::1 at 2021-09-13 22:08:50 -0400
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
MONGODB | Topology type 'unknown' initializing.
MONGODB | There was a change in the members of the 'Unknown' topology.
MONGODB | Server localhost:27017 initializing.
MONGODB | Waiting for up to 3.00 seconds for servers to be scanned: #<Cluster topology=Unknown[localhost:27017] servers=[#<Server address=localhost:27017 UNKNOWN>]>
MONGODB | Error checking localhost:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:27017 (for 127.0.0.1:27017 (no TLS)) (on localhost:27017)
MONGODB | Server description for localhost:27017 changed from 'unknown' to 'unknown'.
MONGODB | There was a change in the members of the 'Unknown' topology.
```

I was able to connect to an Atlas database, but this project requires a local one. I confirmed is not related to my antivirus or firewall. I cannot attempt to connect via mongosh. It just doesn't recognize the "mongosh" command, even thou I added it to the path manually.

Running out of ideas here

Comment: Please check whether mongodb service is running or not. Also install MongoDB Compass which is a GUI client for mongodb database.

Comment: I was able to use mongosh (via powershell) and the connection seems ok, the connection to the db from the app is still not working thou. Same error

Comment: `localhost:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: Errno::ECONNREFUSED` means there is nothing listening on that port.

Comment: i sort of finally fixed it. My system setup included a permanent postgreSQL server (coding bootcamp), although  I didn't try disabling it, most likely it was the cause. I just installed an Ubuntu partition, it was better in the long run.

Comment: May I know what exactly fixed this issue for you @Msantamaria. I am facing similar issue with Mongodb verison 6 and ruby drive version 2.13.2.